# Apache и браузер

Tags: apache, запрос, браузер

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом сервер (Apache) посылает клиенту (браузеру) информацию о том что нужно установить Cookies или получить их?

Comment: в заголовке http запроса.  Вот даже rfc нужный есть в переводе - [rfc2068](http://lib.ru/WEBMASTER/rfc2068/).

Comment: @KoVadim, Не подскажите как их получить (прочитать)

Comment: как Вы их хотите получить? пхп кодом, curl'ом в консоли, Ваш способ.

Comment: Вот мне и хотелось узнать как их получить на стороне клиента! И как вообще получает их браузер?

Comment: @cas-live, почитайте спеку HTTP или хотя бы [википедию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie). В целом запрос-ответ выглядят так

    Заголовки
    (пустая строка)
    тело

Ответ сервера с куками будет примерно таким

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-type: text/html
    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=aaaabbbbccccdddd
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ...

Wireshark или аналог помогут посмотреть на живом примере. Можно даже чере telnet запросить какой-нибудь гугл вручную.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы!